# Update an observable

Tags: java, arraylist, observable, observers

I have a small software for listening to songs. I create a small graphical interface which display the time elapsed, the time to release in labels and a JSlider to know the approximate position in the song. This part of the code is ok.

I'd like, when I move the thumb on the JSlider, update the reading position of the song. In that aim, I implements a Interface "Observable" with a method UpdateObservateur (Observateur = the observer) which have to update the list of the observers.

My problem is : I can reach the method updateObservateur but never updating the observers. In the code beneath, it means I can display the "Simple update", but never the "Complete update". I think it's quite easy to fix that problem but... I didn't found any solution.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class GUITimeDisplayer extends JPanel implements Observable {
private JLabel durationLabel = new JLabel();
private JLabel elapsedTimeLabel = new JLabel();
private JLabel remainedTimeLabel = new JLabel();
private ArrayList<Observateur> listObservateur = new ArrayList<Observateur>();
double position;
private double durationTime, remainingTime, elapsedSec, remainedSec;
private int elapsedMin, remainedMin;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
JSlider time = new JSlider();
boolean timeControl = true;


GUITimeDisplayer(double durationTime) {

    this.durationTime=durationTime;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel timeDisplayer=new JPanel();
    timeDisplayer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    timeDisplayer.add(elapsedTimeLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    timeDisplayer.add(remainedTimeLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    time.setMinimum(0);
    time.setMaximum((int)durationTime);
    time.setPaintTicks(true);
    //time.setPaintLabels(true);
    time.setMinorTickSpacing(20);
    time.setMajorTickSpacing(60);
    if (timeControl == true ) {
        time.addChangeListener(new TestListener() {


        });
    }


    //this.add(durationLabel);
    this.add(timeDisplayer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //this.add(remainedTimeLabel);
    this.add(time, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

class TestListener implements ChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        position = (double)(((JSlider)event.getSource()).getValue());

        //System.out.println(position);
        updateObservateur();
    }

}

public void setDurationTime(double durationTime) {
    this.durationTime=durationTime;
    df.format(durationTime);
    durationLabel.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(durationTime)));
}

public void setElapsedTime(double elapsedTime) {
    if (elapsedTime >= 60) {
        elapsedMin=(int) elapsedTime/60;
        elapsedSec=elapsedTime%60;
        elapsedTimeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(elapsedMin)+":"+String.valueOf(df.format(elapsedSec)));
    } else {
        //elapsedSec=elapsedTime;
        elapsedTimeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(elapsedTime)));
    }
    remainingTime=durationTime-elapsedTime;
    if (remainingTime>=60) {
        remainedMin=(int) remainingTime/60;
        remainedSec=remainingTime%60;
        remainedTimeLabel.setText("-" + String.valueOf(remainedMin)+":"+String.valueOf(df.format(remainedSec)));
    } else {
        remainedTimeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(remainingTime)));
    }
    time.setValue((int)elapsedTime);

}


@Override
public void addObservateur(Observateur obs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.listObservateur.add(obs);

}

@Override
public void delObservateur() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.listObservateur = new ArrayList<Observateur>();

}

@Override
public void updateObservateur() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Simple update : "+position);
    for(Observateur obs : this.listObservateur) {
        obs.updatePosition(position);
        System.out.println("Complete update : "+position);
    }


}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you call addObservateur() anywhere. You need to call it.

Comment: You have to: 1) Add observers, 2) notify observers, and 3) the observers must do something.  If you fail to do these three things, the program will not work.